# How to load json via webpack file-loader?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I need to load several json files via `file-loader` and then in runtime load and parse them via another library, but webpack transpiles json file into js adding `'module.exports =...` at beginning of file.

This config throws error during build:

```
{
  include: ASSETS_SOURCE_PATH,
  use: {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[path][name].[ext]',
    },
  },
},
```

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/map/map.json
Module parse failed: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'module.exports = __w...'
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'module.exports = __w...'
```

And if I change config to this, I catch this error during parsing json in runtime:

```
{
  test: /\.json$/,
  type: 'javascript/auto',
  include: ASSETS_SOURCE_PATH,
  use: {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[path][name].[ext]',
    },
  },
},
{
  include: ASSETS_SOURCE_PATH,
  use: {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[path][name].[ext]',
    },
  },
},
```

Content of this file is `module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "assets/map/map.json";`

UPD: Syntax `import mapTilesJson from '!!file-loader!assets/map/map.json'` works fine, but it may break typescript typings. Is there a way to reach the same effect in webpack config, not inline?

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same issue today. A workaround is to rename the file and change its extension. For example, from "map.json" to "map.json.data". Then load the "map.json.data" file as you load any binary file using file-loader.

Answer (score 1):

you can disable webpack's default json handling by modifying the `file-loader` and setting `type: "javascript/auto"`. for webpacker the change would be in `config/webpack/environment.js` and look like this:

```js
const fileLoader = environment.loaders.get("file")
fileLoader.type = "javascript/auto"
```

see: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruletype